# The art of linking : double-clicking versu adding to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and using command line

Tags: macos, vba, gcc, shared-libraries, dylib

[I am under mac OS X 10.10.5, using gnu 5.2's `g++` designed by `g++-5.2.0` afterwards. I am using in the following *text* interchangeably `so` (linux) and `dylib` (mac os x) extensions for shared libraries.]

I have a shared library libshared2.so that

- was *compiled* by linking to another shared library libshared1.so (both shared libraries are compiled by myself)
- is *used* in two "executables" : in an excel file calling a function defined in the VBA of Excel-2011 for mac and using libshared2.so's function, or in a command-line executable `docalc` compiled by linking to libshared2.so

(details of compilations, referecements in VBA etc can be given if needed, I just didn't want to put them here as the question is almost already tl;dr;)

**1)** All excel, .o, .h, .so/.dylib and Makefile files are in the same directory.

**1) a)** Double clicking the `docalc` to run it or the excel file to run the calculation in it always yields about complaints (by VBA or by dyld) about libshared2.so not being found, having put an

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libshared1/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

(yeah, libshared1, not libshared2, even if complaints are about the latter, see further below) in my `.bash_profile` or not.

**1) b)** Do the previous export in bash (or having put it in `.bash_profile`) and running after the excel file or the command-line executable in the command line (not by double cliking them anymore) makes everything go as intended, without complaint.

**2)** Now the executable (the excel file or the `docalc` command-line executable) is a some place `/.../placeexe`, whereas `/.../placesharelibs/` is a place that can contain either libshared2.so or libshared1.so or both of them.

**2) a)** No miracle, double-clicking still leads, in both cases (excel or command line exectuable), to complaints of the same kind as stated below.

**2) b)** doing an

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/.../placesharelibs/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and *running in the command-line* leads to the following :

- in the case of the `docalc` command-line executable, I have complaint about libshared2.so not being found if and only if i do not put both libshared2.so *and* libshared1.so in `/.../placesharelibs/`.
- in the case of the excel file ran in command-line, I have complaint about libshared2.so not being found if and only if i do not put libshared1.so in `/.../placesharelibs/`.

Why this difference in behaviour ? How could I achive the following : incorporate somehow the `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/.../placesharelibs/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` "into" the double-clicking so that my users could not worry about anything except double-clicking ?

Precision : I don't want to use static libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully read and understand what you are doing, but maybe this helps anyway:

Double-clicking does not read .bash_profile, i.e., your environment variables don't get set. A simple trick to get the same behavior as when calling from the command line is to write a short script that

- exports any `PATH` or other environment variable you need (here `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`)
- calls the executable (perhaps passing command line arguments)

Then, call the script to call your program. This can be by double-clicking or from the command line, or wherever you called your program directly before.